# The wrong data presented with Python

Tags: python, json

```
{
    "created_at": "2016-12-21T13:00:00Z",
    "entry_id": 474,
    "field1": "24.10",
    "field2": "78.00",
    "field3": "0",
    "field4": null
}
```

I want to stretch the data from thingspeak and print the temperature data("field1":"24.10")

```
data = urlopen("http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/148353/feed/last.json?key=K8TNQ7BOCQ3JZMK2").read().decode('utf-8')

dataJson = json.loads(data)
temperature  = dataJson.get('field1')
print(temperature)
print(type(temperature))
```

But the result is not i want：

> none
>
> class 'NoneType'

If i want to print 24.10 then how can i do?

Comment: Strange that `key=MYKEY` doesn't seem to even matter in the url

Comment: If that's really the data you get then your code is correct, so chances are you get something else. Add a line to print out the data you really get....

Comment: oh because the key isn't the key point in my problem, so i use MYKEY replace the true key

Comment: Right, but the JSON that **we** get from the URL you provided is not the same as JSON in this post

Comment: sry,i change into the format that is just my problem：(http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/148353/feed/last.json?key=K8TNQ7BOCQ3JZMK2)

Comment: In Python 3 your code works as expected: `24.10
<class 'str'>` after adding the two lines `import json` and `from urllib.request import urlopen` at the top.

Answer (score 2):

I got a bit different json from your link. So try:

```
temperature = dataJson.get('channel').get('field1')
```

Comment: sry,i change into the format that is just my problem：(http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/148353/feed/last.json?key=K8TNQ7BOCQ3JZMK2)

Comment: @JonathanCheng then your code works fine for me in both Python3.5 and Python2.7. Try to print your `dataJson` to see how it looks.

Answer (score 2):

Edit:- ** Got it working**

You were using wrong syntax, to get a value from a field in json, first load the json, then call by `[]`

```
import urllib, json
url = "http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/148353/feed/last.json?key=K8TNQ7BOCQ3JZMK2"
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
print data['field1']
```

This gives :- `24.10`

Comment: sry,i change into the format that is just my problem：(http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/148353/feed/last.json?key=K8TNQ7BOCQ3JZMK2)

Comment: json.loads() just creates a dictionary object, so using dict.get() is a valid syntax as well as [ ]. This was not the problem, he linked a different json file than what he was actually using.

Comment: the `get()` syntax was fine

Comment: I use py3.4 and the bug: File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 312, in loads
    s.__class__.__name__))

TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'